# Android App cannot see datastore entities created via JSP

Tags: java, android, jsp, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a system based on Google's mobile backend starter example, so an android app reading and writing stuff to the datastore and a jsp website able to do similar things.

In my jsp, I'm adding an entity like this:

```
            Entity ent = new Entity(KeyFactory.createKey(table, "CE:" + UUID.randomUUID().toString()));
            ent.setProperty("_createdAt", new Date());
            ent.setProperty("_createdBy", user);
            ent.setProperty("_kindName", table);
            // owner???
            ent.setProperty("_updatedAt", new Date());
            ent.setProperty("_updatedBy", user);
            ...
            datastore.put(ent);
```

The app itself creates entities of the same kind like this:

```
    CloudEntity newPost = new CloudEntity(kindname);

    newPost.put("propertyname", propertyvalue);

    CloudBackendMessaging cbm = mProcessingFragment.getCloudBackend();
    cbm.insert(newPost, handler);
```

Looking at the datastore in google cloud console, the entities all look the same and I can't see any differences in the actual data formats and layout. It all looks good.

When I run a query from the android app:

```
    mProcessingFragment.getCloudBackend().listByProperty("kindname", "property", Filter.Op.EQ, datastring, Order.DESC, 1000, Scope.PAST, handler);
```

only the entities that have been added from the app are shown. Any help as to what I need to do in the JSP to get the entities to appear would be greatly appreciated.

PS. I tried to delete an entity from the JSP and that is certainly seen by the query so it's not a caching thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally worked this one out. The website was creating the records with fields "_createdBy" and "_updatedBy" set to 'user' where

```
User user = userService.getCurrentUser();
```

These look like all the other strings in Google Developer Console but they're actually not, which you can only tell by editing the individual fields.

When my android app was loading, I assume it loaded all the records up to this one and then stopped with an unreported error (my fault for not reporting the error).

The fix was to create the records with user.toString() instead of just user.

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason for that behavior are namespaces. Namespaces are usually use to isolate data in datastore.

Have you seen if your app has set a datastore namespace?

Comment: I went through the docs and checked the cloud console for a namespace selection on the datastore but I have none so I must assume it's all using the default namespace. I certainly haven't added any code to do this in the past. A shame because that would have explained it. Thanks for the suggestion.